# How to get dynamically generated HTML by JavaScript of web page in C# or Windows forms?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms, web-scraping

I am able to get HTML source code using following code. but when I am trying with https://marriott.medallia.com/sso/marriott/homepage.do?v=bnAaQvo3*lVHsqtnwluPh_CMCsIHyFkti&alreftoken=6d0d31c7eb7583b964d0ecb89b55e12b

The page URL is getting changed dynamically and on next generated page when I see source view I only get the following code in the HTML body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>IdP Selection</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app-container" class="app-container"></div>
  <script>
      AppContext = {
          idps: '[{&quot;entityId&quot;:&quot;MI-PROD-SAML2-IDP-MEDALLIA&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Marriott International (any associate w/ EID)&quot;},{&quot;entityId&quot;:&quot;https://identity.starwoodhotels.com&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Starwood Hotels&quot;}]'
      };
  </script>
  <script src="main.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

when I inspect on generated radio button I am able to get HTML element in browser developer elements tab.

[image]

My C# code is as follows:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new MyScript();
    }
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: window.external.CallServerSideCode();");
    }
[ComVisible(true)]
    public class MyScript
    {
        public void CallServerSideCode()
        {
            var doc = ((Form1)Application.OpenForms[0]).webBrowser1.Document;
            var renderedHtml = doc.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].OuterHtml;
            var marelement = doc.GetElementById("MI-PROD-SAML2-IDP-MEDALLIA");
            HtmlElementCollection eCollections = doc.GetElementsByTagName("HTML");
            string strDoc = eCollections[0].OuterHtml;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific exception when your code runs?

Comment: Code is running fine but i am not able to get generated elements in run time, var marelement = doc.GetElementById("MI-PROD-SAML2-IDP-MEDALLIA"); getting null here. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think It's because of ajax! After ajax previous handler of element is not updates and you should attach handler on OnPropertyChanged event:

```
var element = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0];
element != null ? element.AttachEventHandler("onpropertychange", handler) : return;
private string renderedHtml;

private void handler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      var element = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0];
      if (element != null)
          renderedHtml = element.OuterHtml; 
}
```

Comment: how should i initialize/instantiate target in second line?

Comment: return is still giving error (invalid expression term return)

Comment: I change expression with if (element != null)
            {
                element.AttachEventHandler("onpropertychange", handler);
            }

Comment: @RaviAnand You did right. I just write them on editor quickly without checking. does it work now?

Comment: Yes, project is running fine. but handler is not getting fired. :(

Comment: any help here? or should i share i source code with you?

Answer (score 0):

So the page is rendered by ReactJS so you are going to have a bad time getting this to work. The best thing I can think of is creating a something that 'waits' for the element to be created in the WebBrowserControl....

```
!(function() { 
    function check(){
        if(!document.getElementById("MI-PROD-SAML2-IDP-MEDALLIA")) {
            setTimeout(check, 100);
        } else {
            window.external.CallServerSideCode();
        }
    }
    check();
}());
```

Which can then be minified to something you can use...

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"javascript:!(function(){function c(){if(!document.getElementById('MI-PROD-SAML2-IDP-MEDALLIA')){setTimeout(c, 100);}else{window.external.CallServerSideCode();}}c();}());");
```